# group by primary key vs primary key and dependant columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (a int primary key, b int);

SELECT a, b FROM T1 GROUP BY a;
```

--Msg 8120 Level 16. Column 'T1.b' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I would have expected this to work, since column b is clearly a dependant column, so grouping by a, b is clearly the same as grouping by a.

I am using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support dependent columns in `GROUP BY`.  All databases differ from standard specifications in some respects.  So, although what you want to do is allowed in the standard, not all databases support the functionality.

Just use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT a, MAX(b) as b
FROM T1
GROUP BY a;
```

Or include it in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM T1
GROUP BY a, b;
```

And I should also point out that the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary in this case.  I suspect that this is in reference to more complicated queries where it would be appropriate.

Comment: Haha this title "group by primary key" is interesting indeed. Good point !

Answer (score 0):

If you need  distinct value then use DISTINCT and not group by

SELECT distinct a, b FROM T1

otehrwise  ..use proper aggregation function for column not mentioned in group by clause